# ProgressDialog, activity's onCreate() and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-lifecycle

This question has to do with an `AsyncTask` that needs to kill a `ProgressDialog`. While the task is running, the activity gets destroyed and recreated (phone rotation, for example). A new dialog gets made with the help of `onSaveInstanceState()` but the `AsyncTask`, spawned by the previously destroyed activity, can't see it.

Picture, if you will... (quick mockup code for example's sake).

```
public class Bob extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog m_d;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        m_d = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // ...
        if (b != null) {
            if (b.getBoolean("dialog") == true)
                m_d.show();
        }
        // ...
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
        b.putBoolean("dialog", (m_d.isShowing()));
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (m_d.isShowing()) {
            m_d.dismiss();
            m_d = null;
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

The `AsyncTask` `onPreExecute()` does `m_d.show()` and `onPostExecute()` does `m_d.hide()`.

The problem is when my activity gets recreated (say, on phone rotation), the `AsyncTask` seems to have the old `m_d`. It is `null`, because that got killed in `onDestroy()`.

It doesn't have the new `m_d`, created when the activity got recreated. So now I have a `ProgressDialog` and the guy who was supposed to kill it in `onPostExecute()` can't see it.

Now what? I need the old `AsyncTask` to somehow signal the new `ProgressDialog` to go away.

```
private OnItemSelectedListener onSpinnerSelection = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // ...
        new Switcharoo().execute();
    }
}

private class Switcharoo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        m_d.show();
        // ...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        if (m_d != null) m_d.hide();
        // ...
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If Android doesn't kill my activity while the task is running, it's fine. The `ProgressDialog` pops up and goes away like I expect.

If Android decides to restart my activity for any reason while the task is running, `m_d` will be `null` in `onPostExecute()` even though I recreated it in `onCreate()` - it has the old `m_d`, not the new one.

Comment: add here line where you are executing asynctask.

Comment: Added, though I'm not sure it helps.  Pretty generic.

Comment: Can you hook some code to update m_d when the old activity is destroyed?

Comment: I dunno, can I?  How can I pass the new m_d into the already-running AsyncTask?  Or how can the AsyncTask notify the new Activity that it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: the first is that the `AsyncTask` is bound to the activity that has created it. I mean, the instance of the activity.

If you want it to survive between activities rotations you have to store it somewhere else (check [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html) for example). In any case, you need to have a reference to it from the new activity (another thing you could do is to use a model fragment, i.e. a fragment with no UI that you set as `setRetainInstance(true)`).

Once you have the reference to the async task from the newly created activity, nothing prevents you to have `m_d` local to the async task and a setter method that updates it with the new dialog.

Note also that it would be a good practice to have weak references pointing to the activity and the dialog itself in order to allow garbage collection. Otherwise the dialog (and probably the activity itself) would not be freed until the execution of the task itself ended.

Comment: Sweet Jesus that actually worked.  For those playing along at home, the secret sauce is using "onRetainNonConfigurationInstance" to return the AsyncTask that was first created.  When the activity is destroyed and remade by Android, the new instance uses getLastNonConfigurationInstance to get a pointer to the original AsyncTask.  It can then call soemthing like m_switcharoo.setDialog(m_d) and then, inside Switcharoo it assigns its own m_d to be the passed-in value, which is the new dialog box.

Comment: Note also that fragments apparently replaced all of this and these calls are deprecated in API 13 but I'm coding against API 8.